# We need to update the FAQ now that Gnome-remix is official

Tags: discussion, bug, faq-suggestion

Since [Ubuntu Gnome Remix will become an official Ubuntu derivative](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/its-official-ubuntu-gnome-remix-joins-the-ubuntu-family) upon the release of 13.04, I think it's time we update the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) to reflect that.

Currently it states:

> This is **not** the right place for:
>
> - Linux Mint, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix and other Linux distributions (try our friends at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange).

Obviously if Gnome-remix becomes official it would be supported here right?

---

[Journeymangeek also pointed out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8961639#8961639) that the links to the Ubuntu Code of Conduct and Ubuntu Leadership Code of Conduct lead to the same page.  I guess that needs to be fixed as well.

Comment: It would be appropriate to update the FAQ when BOTH the linked canonical official derivatives page is updated as well as 13.04 is released.

Comment: After we update, we should say:"This is not the right place for Ubuntu GNOME Remix 12.10 ONLY" or that sort of thing.

Comment: There is only one *Code Of Conduct* now - the split has been removed several months ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu Gnome Remix will be off-topic forever. The "new" project, Ubuntu GNOME, will be allowed and on-topic.

Comment: Technically correct, But ubuntu gnome is just a new name for ubuntu gnome remix , so it will cause ambiguity

Comment: Not really. If you're using Gnome Remix you're using an unsupported derivative. If you're using Ubuntu GNOME then you're using a supported derivative

Comment: "Remix" are unofficial derivatives. However the official Ubuntu GNOME flavour in 13.04 does not contain "Remix" and is an official derivative. It qualifies as a supported distribution in Ask Ubuntu. The Remix doesn't though, since it's after all unofficial at that point.

Comment: @smartboyhw So they removed the "remix" part when they made it official?

Comment: @Seth Yes. After all, "remix" means unofficial deriatives. They did try other names, but finally they have to use Ubuntu GNOME, since Gubuntu is too near Goobuntu (the Google internal flavour) and GNOMEbuntu isn't accepted by the GNOME Foundation Board.

Comment: The GNOME Foundation Board were OK with "Ubuntu GNOME", but not "GNOMEbuntu"? How weird.